# Is there any database like firestore for dedicated server?

Tags: node.js, database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

I like to work with Google Firestore (database). But I have some project with private company and they don't want to use cloud, they want use their own server. So, I want to find a database with these features :

1. NoSQL
2. Document-oriented
3. Fast / Scalable
4. Support NodeJS trigger

The No.4 is important thing that make me love Firestore. When user create/update/delete a document, it trigger a NodeJS function (GG cloud function).

Do you know any database like this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### MongoDB.

MongoDB will fit whatever you needs on the list, as long you're willing to explore more.

for #4) https://docs.mongodb.com/stitch/triggers/

Comment: Oh. I heard that MongoDB don't have trigger, that's why I ask. Maybe I'm wrong. Let me check again more carefully. Thank you so much

Comment: if this is considered best answer, pls kindly select as best answer, that would be best for us. Cheers :)